# React Hooks - useState initializes empty array that becomes object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

In the following code, I believe I am initializing gameList as an empty array. The first console.log shows gameList is an empty array. I then use a console.log in useEffect() that displays gameList as an object but I do not believe that I am doing anything to transform gameList. Can anyone explain this? I was trying to pass an array of objects to a child component but even upon using Object.values() on the gameList "object" it is still returning as an object. Thanks!

**Edit**: Perhaps the way I should've has asked this is: "Why does gameList show up in child component as an object with gameList as property? Why does it not arrive in the GameList component as an empty array called gameList? This is happening before submitting my form by the way.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import GameList from './GameList';

const Searchbar = () => {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('');
  const [gameList, setGameList] = useState([]);

  console.log(gameList); // []

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('gameList is ' + typeof gameList); // gameList is object
  });

  const requestGames = searchString => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/game/${searchString}`)
      .then(({ data }) => setGameList(data))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          requestGames(searchString);
        }}
      >
        <label htmlFor="search-string">Search</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="search.."
          onChange={e => setSearchString(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      <GameList gameList={gameList} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Searchbar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays have type `object` in JavaScript:

```js
console.log(typeof []) //=> "object"
```

You can read more about the `typeof` operator on MDN [1].

To check if something is an array you can do this:

```js
console.log(Array.isArray([])) //=> true
```

Or this:

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call([])) //=> "[object Array]"
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Ahh yes of course. I will have to rephrase my question a bit. Because even if I pass that empty array into the <GameList /> it shows up in GameList as an object with a gameList array as a property. That's my real issue.